# Simple function to get city name with Google Maps geocoder reverse

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a small application using HTML 5, Javascript and Google Maps API but I need to do a function to reverse geolocation. I give the latitude and longitude, and show the city where I am.

The code to generate the map I have is set up, I just need a simple function of reverse geolocation

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#ReverseGeocoding